# Unexpected result when copying text

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I copy the letter A, it looks like an empty string is logged to the console. I expect A to be logged.

When I paste, the console successfully logs A.

```js
document.addEventListener('copy', handler);
document.addEventListener('cut', handler);
document.addEventListener('paste', handler);

function handler(e) {
  console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
}
```

```html
A
```

Comment: ["However, the handler cannot read the clipboard data."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event) which btw was also my first thought - being able to programmatically see, what a user copied, doesn't sound like a good idea on the web. At least i'd want a browser, that doesn't let websites see that.

Comment: Try `document.getSelection().toString();` to get the cut/copied value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get the data which was selected during `cut/copy/paste` you can use `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString();` to get the clipboard data

```js
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  const selection = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString();
  debugger;
  console.log(selection);
  event.preventDefault(selection);
});
document.addEventListener('cut', (event) => {
  const selection = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString();
  debugger;
  console.log(selection);
  event.preventDefault(selection);
});
document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
  const selection = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString();
  debugger;
  console.log(selection);
  event.preventDefault(selection);
});
```

```html
AAA
```